# Track a rotation object with encoder with Matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation, encoder

I'm trying to track a rotating object with an encoder using Matlab. 
I have an encoder that gives me the angular position of the object, then I pass this information to a laser, but how can I move the laser at the same velocity of my object? Because now the laser is slower than the object and it does't follow it very well!
I wrote this code, does anyone have any advice?

```
Alpha=pi/2
Positions = [];

t0 = clock;                                

while etime(clock,t0)<20;

  position = data.Position;   %here I read the angular position from the encoder
  Positions = [Positions position];
  A = [floor(Positions/360)];
  angPos = position-(floor(position/360))*360;
  AngPos = [Positions - A*360];
  angRad = angPos*pi/180;
  AngRad = [AngPos*pi/180];

  Angle = angRad+Alpha;
  thetaX = atan(cos(Angle).*(r/d)); 
  thetaY = atan(sin(Angle).*(r/d));

  VoltX=-(5/20)*thetaX*180/pi; 
  VoltY=(5/20)*thetaY*180/pi;    

  VoltageLimit = 10;

  if (max(abs(VoltX))>VoltageLimit) || (max(abs(VoltY))>VoltageLimit)
error('Voltages too large');
  end           

 session.outputSingleScan([VoltX VoltY]);   %here I send the laser the angular position obtained before 

 data = motorA.ReadFromNXT();

end
```

I know that I should add the velocity, so I can move the laser with the same velocity of the object, but I don't know how to give the laser that velocity value!!

```
sec = etime(clock,t0);
Sec = [Sec sec];

vel=(diff(Positions)/diff(Sec));
Vel = [Vel vel]; %(deg/s);
```

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I'm pretty new in Matlab!
Thank you!!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify how your setup looks like, where is the laser relative to the rotating object, how do X- and Y-Voltage affect the aim of your laser?

Comment: The laser must follow a circular path on the plane perpendicular to the laser axis. The voltages move two mirrors that send the laser where I want (the circular path in my case). So, I read the angle position of my object from the encoder, I calculate the voltage values and I send them to the laser...the problem is that the laser gets behind the object with the code I wrote, because I didn't give any information about the velocity or about the time. I would add these but I don't know where exactly in the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you keep track of the last `n = 3` previous angular speeds in some vector `omega = []` that is initialized empty before the loop is entered. You should also memorize a timestamp `prev_t = []` of the previous iteration and also the previous angle `prev_a = []` in order to do this.

In each iteration, you can update your guess for the current angular speed by managing the vector of the `n` previous observed speeds by

```
current_t = clock();
if ~isempty(prev_t)
  if length(omega) == n
    omega(1) = [];
  end
  delta_omega = Angle - prev_a;
  if delta_omega < 0
    delta_omega = delta_omega + 2 * pi; 
  end
  omega = [omega, delta_omega / etime(current_t, prev_t)];
end
prev_t = current_t;
prev_a = Angle;
```

The estimate for the angular speed could be some average of these `n` previous measurements, perhaps `est_omega = median(omega)` to be somewhat robust to outliers. The run-over correction for `delta_omega` assumes that the angle is reported between zero and two pi, and that the angle increases with rotation. You should adjust this correction if your angles behave otherwise.

Then, before you calculate `VoltX` and `VoltY`, you can use your estimate for the current angular speed to predict a corrected `Angle = Angle + est_omega * dt;`, where `dt` is your guess for the delay in your feedback loop. You could choose that empirically. `est_omega` should be calculated, and `Angle` be corrected only `if length(omega) == n`. You don't want to calculate the `median` of an empty list.

Also, I see you calculate x- and y-voltages from some `atan(sin(Angle))` or `atan(cos(Angle))`, respectively. I'm not sure if that is correct. I would believe that these voltages should be proportional to `sin(Angle)` or `cos(Angle)` without `atan` applied.

I would imagine that this solution will work nicely, but for what you are doing here there is a large body of control theory to draw from that may solve your problem in a more sophisticated way.

Comment: About the voltages, it is correct to calculate in that way because they are proportional to the angles thetaX and tethaY, that are the mirrors' angles (they are'not proportional directly to the sin and cos).

Comment: Aha, thanks for the clarification on how you control the mirrors. Good luck.